# Working with date picker in jquery, display today

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want the datepicker to select the currentdate/today and display it instead of'dd----yyyy'and moreover i wanted the date before today to be disabled from selection, please help!

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button_id").click(function () {
        $('<div/>', {
            id: "div_id"
        }).append($('<input>', {
            type: "date",
            name: "someDate",
            class: "date_id"
        })).appendTo("#static_div");
        $(".date_id").datepicker({
            //i want the datepicker to select the currentdate/today and display it instead of'dd----yyyy'and moreover i wanted the date before today to be disabled from selection
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the link to my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/L4reds/73pEN/1/

Comment: you can't have more than one object with the same id, use css classes instead. :)

Comment: you want it to select a day and at the same time give you a choice? I'm not understanding your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button_id").click(function () {
        var div = $('<div/>', {id: "div_id"}),
            inp = $('<input>', {type: "text",name: "someDate",id: "date_id"});

        div.append(inp).appendTo("#static_div");
        inp.datepicker({
            minDate: 0
        }).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/73pEN/3/)

Comment: just what i wanted.. thank you so much.... i'll accept this answer after 8mins.. :D :D :D

Answer (score 0):

Use **minDate** and **maxDate** options to hide the previouse date [see this](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
 });
```

Format option [set using this option](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats)

Answer (score 0):

To disable dates before the current day:

```
 $("#date_id").datepicker({
     minDate: 0
 });
```

Read the documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate